# Change drive letter for CD drive on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

How to change the drive letter for CD drive on Windows 7? I want to map network location to the letter that is currently used by my CD drive.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Right click on the Computer icon on the Desktop and select Manage option.

Select `Storage` > `Disk Management` or just run `diskmgmt.msc` (administrative rights needed).

Right click on the CD/DVD icon in the Disk (bottom) panel and select `Change Drive Letter and Paths...`. If there is a readable disc inserted, you can also select its mounted volume in the top panel.

Change the letter and select OK.

[image: Change Drive Letter and Paths]

Comment: Would just like to add (only because mine wasn't showing up) that there must be a disk in the CD/DVD drive for it to show up in the Disk Management area.

Comment: For future readers, I had what appeared to be a CD drive showing up in Windows Explorer taking up a drive letter, but it didn't show up in Disk Management. It turned out to be Power ISO software I had installed. I just right clicked the drive and changed the Power ISO option to free up that drive letter.

Comment: "there must be a disk in the CD/DVD drive" this is a VERY useful hint. thank you @user55925

Comment: Nowadays (or on my Windows 10 21H1 installation with an USB CD/DVD drive) it is not required to be a disk inside, it is shown anyway.

Comment: There was never a need for a disc to be in the drive, but in that case you can also change the letter from the Volumes panel. I've updated the answer.