# Changing CD-ROM/DVD-ROM Drive Letter from D: to E:

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive, drive-letter, compact-disc, disk-management

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/81286/change-drive-letter-for-cd-drive-on-windows-7), but it doesn't address one question I've had about this (I'd comment on it, but my rep isn't high enough):

When changing the ODD Drive Letter from D: to E:, I get this message in Windows 7:

```
Some programs that rely on drive letters might not run correctly.
Do you want to continue?
```

What programs specifically need to address the D: drive from the aspect of an ODD?  I was of the impression that most programs can dynamically work around this, especially since most developers account for the possibility that the ODD isn't always going to be assigned to the D: drive letter?  Also, I don't have any backups, batch files, VBScripts or any other user-manipulated variables that would reference the D: drive, at least, not to my knowledge.

So would it be safe to assume that I'm not doing any harm by changing my ODD to the D:\ drive letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Badly written ones, or ones that are already installed may have issues. Some applications check to see if the CD is in a specific drive, and if not fail - so for most part, games.

For installing new applications it should be agnostic to what drive you're using for the installer.

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-interpreting the warning message here. It is not about the drive letter `D:` being the optical drive, but about programs and documents with explicit references to data stored on `D:` - which you are breaking by changing the drive letter.

You will see this warning for any drive letter change, not just the one involving an optical disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs, especially those that rely on media in the cdrom, will store that the cdrom is in drive E: or whatever.  It is best to set the drive fairly early, and to a high letter.

I follow the eComStation and have the ram drive in R: and the cdrom in S: