# Change optical drive names in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I seem to recall in some version of Windows, that I was able to assign names to my optical drives for when they aren't in use.  I'm now running Windows 7 Ultimate x64, and trying to find that functionality again.  Was it a figment of my imagination, or is it just somewhere I haven't looked?

To be clear, I'm looking to change the *name* of the drive - not the letter.  For example, a drive that currently shows in Explorer as "BD-ROM Drive (E:)" I would like to change to "DAEMON Tools Drive (E:)".

Comment: You should search first : http://superuser.com/questions/81286/change-drive-letter-for-cd-drive-on-windows-7

Comment: @nXqd - Thanks, but this is not the function I'm looking for.  Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: somehow I don't know why you want to do this, I'm just curious.

Comment: As an educated guess I would say that the name is embedded in the device driver.  I right clicked on the drive in "Computer" selected properties, selected properties again, and went to the details tab.  If you use the drop down it gives you the different "names" for your device, but I couldn't find one that matched with the label displayed for it in Explorer.

Comment: @nXqd - I would like to have a bit more uniqueness between, say "BD-ROM Drive (E:)" and "BD-ROM Drive (F:)".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not the perfect solution, but you can go to the registry and look for:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

1. There, create a new key called `DriveIcons`.
2. Within that key, create another one named like the drive letter you want to change the name for (e.g. `C`)
3. Within that key, create another one named `DefaultLabel`
4. Right click and *Modify* the key's value. There, enter the desired label name. We'll take  `My own Label`
5. Close the registry editor. The settings should be applied immediately. If not, first try to just refresh the Computer window by hitting F5 or -- in Windows Vista or 7 -- clicking Alt -> View -> Refresh. If that doesn't work, a reboot will certainly do.

#### Effect on local drives

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

#### Effect on optical drives

Unfortunately, it doesn't work perfectly on optical drives, only appending the label to the drive's name and letter:

[image]

To undo, remove the key named like the drive.

<sub>[Original Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/66118-drive-rename.html)</sub>

Comment: Now that's just plain awesome.