# Changing drive names in windows 7 won't stick

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, rename

Tried the Admin Tools route, tried right-click "Rename" over the drive icon and also tried [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/283915/change-optical-drive-names-in-windows-7?s=1%7C1.2690), which as far as I can tell, does not really rename the drive but the usb port where it is installed. If you swtich an USB from F to G, the drives name will not show, only the one you created in the registry for the F and G drive entries, meaning that whichever drive you stick in to F will have THAT name, but not the drive's name. I've already removed those entries and since restarted my machine.

What could be a logical reason for drive names not showing in my system's explorer? They show in the Administrative Tools window and if I plug my USB drives in other machines, I can see the drive name I changed, but not on mine.

[image: drive names don't show in explorer]

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Could you identify a file or folder `autorun.inf` on your drive? Maybe attributed system, hidden, read only...

Comment: Not really, no. I will look for that file. I know it can be hidden or missing, but I haven't checked that option. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Maybe your antivirus software prevents file explorer from reading that info?